# JAXB - How to convert custom Date objects to java.util.Date for generated beans?

Tags: xml, date, data-binding, jaxb, xsd

I'm a JAXB beginner.

I have a XSD provided by a third (I cannot modify it) that defines its own Date object instead of using *xs:dateTime*.

I'm also using a Maven plugin to dynamically generate the beans from the XML schema and I externalize custom binding in a XJB file.

**How can I configure the XJB file to use *java.util.Date* instead of the custom Date object in the generated beans?**

The custom Date object in the XML schema is:

```
<xs:element name="Date">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="Time" type="xs:time" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="Date" type="xs:date" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="TimeZone" type="xs:NMTOKEN" use="optional"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```